# Plugins | sfDoctrineGuardPlugin - set a group to user from frontend

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need to set a Group to a user in frontend application. Here what i have done.

```
$g = sfGuardGroupTable::getInstance()->findOneById(1);

$u = new sfGuardUser();
$u->setFirstName($request->getParameter('first_name'));
$u->setLastName($request->getParameter('last_name'));
$u->setEmailAddress($request->getParameter('email_address'));  
$u->setSfGuardUserGroup($g);
$u->save();
```

The user is inserted successfully but I cannot set a group to a user.

Answer (score 0):

There's a many to many relation between sfGuardUser and sfGuardGroup, therefore each sfGuardUser has a collection of sfGuardGroup objects. You have to get the collection and add group to it:

```
$u->getSfGuardUserGroup()->add($g);
```